# How critical will be Samarium Cobalt Magnets to the US war effort in case of a war in Taiwan strait with China?

Tags: united-states, military, geopolitics, national-security, industrial-policy

I am working on a case study as part of my MPhil research project in regards to which I want to know the importance of Samarium Cobalt (SmCo) magnets to the US military in case of a large scale war.

It is widely known that Samarium Cobalt (SmCo) magnets are critical to high-tech military equipment and are excessively used by the military industrial complex as a whole. These are also know to have very fragile supply chain. Samarium is a rare earth metal (with almost all of its supply controlled by China) while Cobalt is also a very important critical metal.

Is there any other engineered component (with supply disruption risk) which may has importance greater then the Samarium Cobalt Magnets in war situation for the US?

Comment: "It is widely known that Samarium Cobalt (SmCo) magnets are critical to high-tech military equipment and are excessively used by the military industrial complex as a whole." Is it? I've never heard of them before, and [Wikipedia makes no mention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samarium%E2%80%93cobalt_magnet#Uses) of them being used in military applications. Can you provide some sort of source to back up your claims?

Comment: "Dear enemy, we wish to inform you that, in case we get into a state of war with you, we would have serious strategic troubles if you were to interrupt our supply of X, so please do not do that. Regards, USA Department of Defense." This information would not be public.

Comment: And of course, it depends on a lot of factors. For a short war, something that is vital in building ships would not be relevant, as the war would end before any new ship was commissioned. For other materials of everyday use, like fuel, strategic reserves can be stored. But a long war gives time to research alternative sources (or even substitutes) for the critical supplies. if you are defending against an enemy that has hypersonic missiles probably components to build your own hypersonic missiles might be vital, against other enemies without that technology, not so much...

Comment: I am concerned about long wars like e.g., conflict for 3 years

Comment: @Engr.MoizAhmad Most studies either predict a war of less than a month with massive losses https://www.cnn.com/2023/01/09/politics/taiwan-invasion-war-game-intl-hnk-ml/index.html or a long blockade that depletes little military gear https://www.realcleardefense.com/articles/2023/02/07/is_the_us_over-militarizing_its_china_strategy_880083.html So a long war where the ability to manufacture replacement material is pivotal like WWII is so unlikely it really isn't even worth considering. And as SJuan76 notes, in a long war there would be time to find materials alternative sources or substitutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question #1:**

> How critical will be Samarium Cobalt Magnets to the US war effort in case of a war in Taiwan strait with China?

Samarium Cobalt Magnets with their higher temperature tolerances are an important component of modern missiles, aircraft, smart bombs and other U.S Defense Dept. weapon systems.  Very critical.

> **Question #2:**
>
> The underlying question is how exposed is the US military to the **[ongoing Chinese boycott of exporting rare earth metals](https://www.skynews.com.au/world-news/china/china-places-restrictions-on-rare-earth-exports/video/9d0c18735dc40e7ebaf81e47f3a708df)**.

> **Short Answer:**

The U.S. military is minimally exposed to shortages due to a Chinese boycott of this important components.  The U.S. total economy is more exposed in the short term as it stands up and shifts to alternate supply chain sources.  The U.S. Military has contingencies in place to mitigate the short term market disruptions.  The U.S. Government and it's allies have contingencies to eliminate the long term market distruptions.

In General using commodities as weapons isn't as effective against militaries. It's a little more effective against economies, but is a two sided sword.

#1  The price shocks from such efforts tend to curtail the civil use and free up supplies which could be used by the military.  The Military needs amounts to a small fraction of the overall economy.

#2  Alternative global suppliers are incentivized to ramp up production

#3  Alternate domestic suppliers ramping up production becomes a new national priority

#4  The collective embargo boosts collaboration among allies

#5  The blow back from such actions has been extreme for China, which signaled to their largest trade partners they were unreliable suppliers.

**Answer:**

Rare Earth Metals aren't Rare.  Many countries including the United States have them.  China's "monopoly" in the production of Rare earth metals is not based on a unique access to the ores, rather it's based upon the price point of their end product; and their domestic willingness to accept the ecological cost of participating in this market on a large scale.  Thus the ongoing boycott of these materials creates short term supply shortages but not long term issues as the supply chain naturally adjusts.

The U.S. economy consumed about 450 tons of Samarium Cobalt in 2022.

> **[North America Samarium Cobalt Magnets Market:](https://www.imarcgroup.com/north-america-samarium-cobalt-magnets-market)**
> The North America samarium cobalt magnets market size reached 454.1 Tons in 2022. Looking forward, IMARC Group expects the market to reach 525.6 Tons by 2028,

U.S. Defense accounts for about **[five percent of US consumption](https://www.airandspaceforces.com/article/rare-earth-uncertainty/)** or 23 tons per year.   US government stock piles of samarium cobalt as of 2022 were **[50 tons](https://pubs.usgs.gov/periodicals/mcs2022/mcs2022-rare-earths.pdf)**.  However at 5% of domestic consumption U.S. Defense Dept. needs could easily be made up by alternative domestic or international suppliers.

The **[US was the #1 producer of rare earth metals for decades](https://www.army.mil/article/227715/an_elemental_issue)** decades ago.  The U.S. never ran out of rare earth metals **[in 2003 U.S. shut down domestic production because companies preferred to purchase from China due to costs](https://www.zdnet.com/article/americas-only-rare-earth-metals-mine-gears-up/)**.  Efforts to restore U.S. domestic production or rare earth metals began in 2012, but faced fiscal limitations due to continued low cost Chinese supplies.  **[In 2020 U.S production of REM amounted to about 16% of global supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_Pass_mine)**. As of 2022 the U.S Defense Department began funding the expansion U.S. domestic production of Rare Earth Metals.

These efforts to increase domestic production are also occurring around the world.